# How to train dialogflow for extracting values may not be split by space

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm creating a chatbot that needs to recognize an intent by a {amount + currency} message

for example, when a chatbot see any of the these: 
"USD500 / USD 500 / 500USD / 500 USD", it should give intent=A, amount=500, currency = USD.

I tried to list all 4 cases in the as the training phrases, then the chatbot can only recognize USD. If the user gives "500EUR", the chatbot can't recognize.

Basically, I want to train the chatbot to recognize the pattern of {Currency}+{optional space}+{amount} and {amount}+{optional space}+{currency}.

To have the chatbot work for all world currencies, how should I set up the to training?

Comment: Just to clarify, have you tested it with the `@sys.unit-currency` [system entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/system-entities)?

Comment: Tried both sys.unit-currency and sys.currency-name, they works only when there is space between the number and the currency. e.g. 50 USD works, but 50USD doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using separate slots for `@sys.number` and `@sys.currency-name`.

With these setting (language: German) I could create your desired behavior.
[image: Dialogflow Intent Screen]

Comment: That's what I would have suggested as well, and you might also consider wrapping the two types into a [composite entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities#developer_composite) for easier handling and parsing.

Comment: iirc composite entities didn't let me use an entity followed by another entity without a space.

Comment: @JDK - using your suggestion, it works for 800USD or USD800, and it works for "JPY 400", however, it doesn't work with "JPY400" (no space in between). I need dialogflow to recognize the common currencies automatically, without entering rules for each currency.